# WordPress: Creating a search form for custom post types

Tags: wordpress, search, custom-post-type

What should I look into if I want to build a form that searches through custom post types, i.e. a completely rebuilt form? Creating the actual form and it's elements is no problem but the next steps brings up a lot of tricky questions such as,

1. How can I pass `$_GET` data to another file maintaining WordPress's permalinks intact ?
2. How can I process the posts without having to create a pyramid of if statements and rather use WordPress's own core functionalities ?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the code below and put your version of it in the functions.php file. This should work perfectly. You might have to replace the ‘ and ’ with apostrophes ‘.

```
add_action(‘init’, ‘product_register’);

function product_register() {
    $args = array(‘label’ => __(‘Products’), ‘singular_label’ => __(‘Product’), ‘public’ => true, ‘show_ui’ => true, ‘capability_type’ => ‘post’, ‘hierarchical’ => false, ‘rewrite’ => true, ‘supports’ => array(‘title’, ‘editor’, ‘thumbnail’));

    register_post_type(‘product’, $args);
}
add_action(“admin_init”, “admin_init”);
add_action(‘save_post’, ‘save_price’);

function admin_init() {
    add_meta_box(“prodInfo - meta”, “Product Options”, “meta_options”, “product”, “side”, “low”);
}

function meta_options() {
    global $post;
    $custom = get_post_custom($post - > ID);
    $price = $custom["price"][0];
    echo‘ < label > Price: < /label><input type=”text” name=”price” value=”‘. $price .’” / > ’;
}

function save_price() {
        global $post;
        update_post_meta($post - > ID, “price”, $_POST["price"]);
    }
    // custom table columns
register_taxonomy(“catalog”, array(“product”), array(“hierarchical” => true, “label” => “Catalogs”, “singular_label” => “Catalog”, “rewrite” => true));
```